# How to leave only the first word in each line with sed, cut or awk?

Tags: regular-expression

I have a big list with the following format:

```
info1 info2 info3 info4
```

Each line has these four fields. How can I use regular expressions to remove all the words except the first word for every line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a space separates your words, you don't need to use a regular expression to extract only the first space-delimited word.  Instead, use `cut` with space as the delimiter:

```bash
cut -d ' ' -f 1 file
```

You may also use `awk`, which uses runs of either consecutive spaces or tabs as its field separator by default, to print only the first field from each line.  This is another case where using a regular expression is not necessary.

```bash
awk '{ print $1 }' file
```

Use `-F ' '` with the above if you want only to use single spaces as the separator.

If you really *need* to use a regular expression (to make some teacher happy, for example), then use one with the substitution command in `sed`:

```bash
sed 's/ .*//' file
```

This command removes (replaces with nothing) everything from the first space character to the end of each line.